# typeOf without using getClass() or instanceof

Tags: java, types, int, typeof

I am currently trying to use System.out.print to give out the type out of an integer x. However from what I've found the only functions simular to typeOf are getClass, which does not work on int, or instanceof, which seems to only work with an if. Is there any other command I could try or am I stuck with `System.out.print("Integer")`?

Comment: Why do you need to know the type of a literal? The literal itself tells you its type. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you need to check if the element is an `int`? Note that you can use `int.class`.

Comment: I dont need it to check, but to give out which element is. I am trying to find a way to do it without a string since I prolly will end up changing the type of the object a few times while working on it

Comment: Ok, then please describe what you're doing. This looks like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Please learn Java before asking this type questions. Integer x could be of class Integer (in such case you can use getClass() for this variable) or of primitive int (this case make you clear understanding what is in variable). You cannot check this - only find out in variable declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that Java is statically typed language. There's no need to check the variable primitive type at runtime, because it's known at compile time and cannot change. For example, if you declare

```
int x = 5;
```

Then `x` cannot be anything else other than `int`, so trying to do something like `typeof(x)` (like in some other languages) is meaningless.

You can generalize the variable type assigning it to the `Object` reference type:

```
int x = 5;
Object obj = x;
```

But even in this case `obj` will not be `int`. In this case Java compiler will automatically box your `x` to `Integer` type, so `obj.getClass().getName()` will return `java.lang.Integer` and `obj instanceof Integer` will return true.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there is no sane reason to do this if you know the type, you don't need a function to work it out for you.

The only time this is useful is when you can't work out the type, e.g. because you are learning and the type is not obvious.  You can implement this using an overloaded function like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = 1;
    byte a = 2;
    System.out.println("The type of a+b is "+typeOf(a+b));
    long l = 1;
    float f = 2;
    System.out.println("The type of l+f is "+typeOf(l+f));
}
public static String typeOf(byte b) {
    return "byte";
}
public static String typeOf(char ch) {
    return "char";
}
public static String typeOf(short s) {
    return "short";
}
public static String typeOf(int i) {
    return "int";
}
public static String typeOf(long i) {
    return "long";
}
public static String typeOf(float i) {
    return "float";
}
public static String typeOf(double i) {
    return "double";
}
public static String typeOf(boolean b) {
    return "boolean";
}
public static String typeOf(Object o) {
    return o.getClass().getName();
}
```

prints

```
The type of a+b is int
The type of l+f is float
```